# Keep php session from expiring when browser is quit

Tags: php, session

I'm working with a PHP session. It's working nicely, except if I quit my browser and then return to the webpage, the session has expired. How can I prevent this/set an expiration time for the session?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the [session.cookie_lifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) configuration setting?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: I'd make it an answer in combination with `session.gc_maxlifetime`...

Comment: Server-side sessions are meant to expire when the browser session ends (i. e. the browser is closed). If you want to store some information beyond that, you shouldn’t use server-side sessions.

Comment: @Gumbo What else is there? You could fake it with the normal cookie interface, but wouldn't you just end up replicating the "set an id in the cookie, retrieve the related data" pattern anyway?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc That depends on the purpose of that ID.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the configuration of `session.cookie_lifetime` so that the browser doesn't just throw your session's cookie away when it's closed (you just give it a number of seconds, and it sets the expiration date)...

```
// assuming you can't change your php.ini file
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 3600); // one hour
```

...But how long do you want the session to remain viable? Because another configuration setting you'd need to worry about is [`session.gc_maxlifetime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime), which sets (again, in seconds) how long session data is allowed to exist (unchanged, I believe?) before it is considered garbage.

The default for `session.gc_maxlifetime` is 1,440 seconds, or about 24 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the security risks mentioned. to extend the session lifetime, 
you can set the lifetime of the session cookie before starting the session  as follows.

```
                     $lifetime=60*60*24*14;   //2 weeks in seconds. you can change the time as you wish
                     session_set_cookie_params($lifetime, '/');
                     session_start();
```

Comment: Isnt a session cookie terminated after browser closes?